# Acessing samba shares on different internal network with different IP range

Tags: networking, ssh, router, ip, samba

[image: Topography]

As you can probably see from my topography, my Raspberry Pi is directly connected to the ISP modem/router with an IP of 192.168.1.2, whereas my PC is one network underneath with an IP of 10.0.0.4.

I was wondering, how can I access shares on my Raspberry pi (Samba Server) on my PC and other smartphones on the 10.0.0.x network? I tried connecting my PC directly to the ISP modem/router, it got an IP of 192.168.1.3 and was able to access the shares, therefore there is no problem in Samba configuration. But when behind the D-Link router, it does not show up when I click "Netowkr" in Explorer.

I can still ping the RPi and SSH to it though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some trial and error, I found out the answer myself.

It won't show up in the "Network" age in explorer, but it can be accessed by typing in run:

`\\192.168.1.2\Stuff`, where Stuff is the name of the share.

Alternatively, you can Map a Network Drive to (in my Computer) `\\192.168.1.1\Stuff`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific requirement for both the 10.0.0.0 and 192.168.1.0 networks?

If not, you could look into running your ISP modem router in bridge mode (disable NAT and DHCP), and plugging your Pi into the other router.

This would eliminate the second network in the first place (192.168.1.0/24). This means your PI would be on the same network as your other devices.

If you can ping and SSH to machine, that means that your networks can talk to each other and (depending on OS) you will be able to remotely connect to, mount, or map the drives. Network discovery presumably wont work over different networks/subnets, hence why the drives don't show up by default.

Comment: The reason I wanted my Pi on the 192 network was because of other factors preventing me from using the 10 network (read: humans)